# Why is Woocommerce getting 542.67 after 271.34 is multiplied by 2?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a cart with a product that costs **USD 271.34**. When I update quantity to 2, the price total changes to **542.67**, instead of **542.68**.

I'm stuck because this value brings along discrepancies that paypal can't check it out, hence generating error no. **10413 - The totals of the cart item amounts do not match order amounts.**

Comment: Your price most likely includes taxes of some sort, which means it might be a rounded value. You will have to add some code to the paypal gateway to trick PP.

Answer (score 1):

Its rounding problem in woo commerce check out :

**Reason**
paypal receives 542.68 and so with any quantity greater than 1 there is a mismatch in paypal’s calculation of the amount and WooCommerce’s.So this error happen.

**Solution**

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_excluding_tax', 'round_price_product', 10, 1 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_including_tax', 'round_price_product', 10, 1 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_tax_round', 'round_price_product', 10, 1);
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price', 'round_price_product', 10, 1);
    function round_price_product( $price ){
        // Return rounded price
        return round( $price);
    }
```

**Reference**

Other Answer that I found,

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/price-rounding-issues-in-paypal/

Comment: `wp-content/themes/functions.php` add code in functions.php

Comment: I assume that you are aware with `round()`,If not then you can find round function here,http://www.w3schools.com/Php/func_math_round.asp

Comment: please check reference link